# How to use Microsoft Graph API to get access to a private site in SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Failed to access a private site in my Sharepoint by using Microsoft  Graph Explorer (Graph API 1.0)

Not sure if I use the correct term (i.e. private site) for it. But that is what I mean by private site.

[What I mean by private site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wketF.png)

I tried to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=PrivateSite1` in the Graph Explorer.

Actual results: `{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites",
    "value": []
}`

expected results: the information for that private site.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Hey, what flow are you using? If you are utilizing the client credentials flow, most likely you are unable to find the site because it's private. And you'll either need to give that service principal access to the sharepoint site, or utilize a delegated permissions flow using a user that has access to that site to get that information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing the client credentials flow, most likely you are unable to find the site because it's private. And you'll either need to give that service principal access to the SharePoint site, or utilize a delegated permissions flow using a user that has access to that site to get that information.